# Каков алгоритм создания такого интерфейса?

Tags: алгоритм, css

https://dribbble.com/shots/1752877-Clean-e-commerce-website/attachments/284571

Как генерируются размеры, а также позиции блоков?

Answer (score 1):

Можно руками, есть паттерны в различных фреймворках, например, [refills в bourbon](http://refills.bourbon.io/).

Answer (score 1):

Похоже на то, что Вам необходимо посмотреть материал по модульным сеткам-для примера http://m.habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/140715/